# What abbreviation should we use?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should we enforce consistent abbreviating?](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42/should-we-enforce-consistent-abbreviating)

Following on from [Should we enforce consistent abbreviating?](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42/should-we-enforce-consistent-abbreviating), could we vote on an abbreviation for consistency?

- **RaspPi**
- **Raspi**
- **RPi**
- **RP**
- **The Pi/Pi**
  (Could this be confusing with 3.14?)

Comment: @KyleMacey As I mentioned before - this is not a duplicate, it is a follow on question to decide upon an abbreviation for consistency.

Comment: I thought that it was decided that we shouldn't abbreviate. Am I wrong?

Comment: @dunsmoreb it's 6 votes for No vs. 5 for Yes, don't think we can call it just yet

Comment: @Alex I think we can. It has been a week since the question was asked. I think it is safe to say that the majority has decided that we **aren't** abbreviating.

Answer (score 4):

**Raspi**, or **RasPi**

The Raspberry Pi foundation use it - see the Raspberry Pi [FAQ](http://www.raspberrypi.org/faqs):

> We will release a datasheet for the SoC which will cover the hardware exposed on the **Raspi** board e.g. the GPIOs. We will also release a board schematic later on.

It's short, not easily confused with other devices, and already in (partial) use.

Comment: I feel like I remember some official source using "Ras Pi" although I can't find it right now.  For those of us just looking for something passable as we write Q&As "RasPi" seems pretty hard to go wrong with.

Answer (score 3):

I say Rpi or R-Pi, but does it really matter? As long as the tags and titles are consistant (And it should not be in either of them at all) then surely that is fine?

Answer (score 1):

It's all subjective, but "Pi" gets my vote. Short, to the point and I really can't see it getting confused with 3.14159265358979323846 - the context should be clear enough.

I think what's more important is that we have a consistent abbreviation, so if we chose to go with another acronym I'm not going to kick up a fuss.

Answer (score 1):

I know what the folks on raspberrypi.org prefer, but for entering questions, comments and answers on StackExchange, I vote for "the Pi" or "Pi" depending on context. Any variation of "raspi" takes both hands on a QWERTY kbd, while Pi uses just the right hand (and the left pinky if you prefer Left-Shift over Right-Shift). Also, in this forum, the other three or four characters are unnecessary.

"Pi" is fast, it's small, it's easy, and it's clear and unambiguous.

Comment: +1 for mentioning how you type it!

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you want, as long as it gets the point across and will be understood.

Comment: I think maybe this answer belongs on [the previous question](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/42/should-we-enforce-consistent-abbreviating).